# Client disconnects from SignalR huhb every 1:03 hours

Tags: c#, signalr

We are running 2 SignalR hubs. Both are separate Windows Console applications.
Hub2 signs up for Hub1 (so Hub2 is a client of Hub1)

Every hour and 3 minutes Hub2 gets disconnected from Hub1 and reconnects after 15 seconds.

It is unacceptable for us that Hub2 disconnects ever from Hub1. Both are running on the same machine.

What could cause this issue?

I've been searching for 2 days now, for a solution or at least a similar case. The only similar cases I found were fixed with the release of v1.1 . We are using v2.2